# Query to match columns from two table with same area code for telephone number

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm trying to write a query to find matches from two tables having the same area code for telephone number.
e.g

```
Employee(name, telephone#)
Customer(name, telephone#)
```

Need to find name of employees with the same telephone area code(xxx-yyy-zzzz) as that of customer(xxx-yyy-zzzz). I can't specify the area code myself. Query should evaluate that. Maybe something like "LIKE" can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substr` and `join` on the first 3 characters of the telephone column.

```
select e.name
from employee e 
inner join customer c on substr(e.telephone, 1, 3) = substr(c.telephone, 1, 3)
```